# Tkinter Line Numbers library not showing numbers properly

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm building a program, but my tkinter Line Numbers library is not working. This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes
from tklinenums import TkLineNumbers

ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(600)
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Blueconda Editor")
window.geometry("1200x600")
window.resizable(False,False)
window.configure(bg='white')


window.rowconfigure(0,weight=1)
window.rowconfigure(1,weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
window.columnconfigure(1,weight=10)
window.columnconfigure(2,weight=0)

#menubar canvas
C = tk.Canvas(width=1200,height=50,bg="white")
C.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=6)

logoimage = tk.PhotoImage(file="src/Bluecondalogo.png")
logo = tk.Label(window, image=logoimage, bg="white")
logo.place(x=10,y=0)

logolabel = tk.Label(text="Blueconda",fg="blue",bg="white")
logolabel.place(x=60,y=15)

def resize(event):
    usertext.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=usertext.yview)
window.bind("<Configure>", resize)

#Codebox
usertext = tk.Text(width=90,borderwidth=0)
usertext.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky="W",pady=0)
fontnew=("Segoe UI SemiBold",12,"bold")
usertext.configure(font=fontnew)
logolabel.configure(font=fontnew)
usertext.configure(bg="white")


scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(window, command=usertext.yview)
usertext['yscrollcommand'] = scrollbar.set
scrollbar.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky="NSW")

# Create the TkLineNumbers widget and pack it to the left
linenums = TkLineNumbers(window, usertext, justify="left", colors=("#000000", "#ffffff"))
linenums.grid(row=1,column=0,sticky="NSW",pady=0)
# Redraw the line numbers when the text widget contents are modified
usertext.bind("<<Modified>>", lambda event: window.after_idle(linenums.redraw), add=True)


window.mainloop()
```

The code has two issues:
The TkLineNums only updates up to 1 and 2, and then stops.
The scrollbar is on the right, but I want it on the left

I'm not sure what's causing both errors because I'm a new programmer. I tried asking ChatGPT but it didn't know either. Any help is appreciated.
(Also this is my first question on stack overflow)

Comment: Also, you can delete the line that includes the "Bluecondalogo.png" image. Realized too late that you all wouldn't have it. Sorry!

Comment: You can edit the code after posting it

Comment: The line numbers will be updated only when first character input (due to event `<<Modified>>`) or the display region of the text box is changed (due to override of `usertext["yscrollcommand"]` internally by `tklinenums` module).  But the later one is override again by your event binding of `<Configurae>`.

Comment: If you want the scrollbar put at the left, why do you put it at column 2? Also it is not clear you want to put the scrollbar to left of the text box or left of the line numbers.

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria Thanks, I didn't know that. sorry!

Comment: @acw1668 regarding your comment on the scrollbar, I found out that the issue was that since there were 3 columns, the scrollbar was actually working fine, position wise. I learned that tk rows in .grid() don't actually appear until something is placed in them and I thought I would see some blank space at the right of the scrollbar. So yea, dumb overlook by me

Comment: Also, @acw1668, the line numbers didn't update at all no matter what I did. I spammed enter, or typed stuff.

Comment: `def resize():
    usertext.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
    scrollbar.config(command=usertext.yview)
    window.after(1000, resize)`

I tried using timers instead of binding the functions to the widgets. In the above example, I'm modifying the scrollbar every second based on the size of the text. It works fine!!! I can also setup as many as I want, so no conflicts of widgets!

Answer (score 0):

Since `TkLineNumbers` override the `.yscrollcommand()` function of the text widget so that it can update itself when the display region of the text box is changed.  However it breaks the relation between the text box and the scrollbar.

Also event `<<Modified>>` will not be triggered if the internal *modified* flag is not reset.

There is *workaround* on the above issues:

```py
...

# below binding is not necessary
#def resize(event):
#    usertext.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
#    scrollbar.config(command=usertext.yview)
#window.bind("<Configure>", resize)

...

def on_scroll(*args):
    scrollbar.set(*args)  # update scrollbar
    window.after_idle(linenums.redraw) # update line numbers

def on_modified(event):
    usertext.edit_modified(False) # reset the internal modified flag
    window.after_idle(linenums.redraw) # update line numbers

# override the yscrollcommand
usertext.config(yscrollcommand=on_scroll)
# Redraw the line numbers when the text widget contents are modified
usertext.bind("<<Modified>>", on_modified, add=True)

window.mainloop()
```

Note that the reset of the internal *modified flag* may have side effect on the behaviour of the text box.

Comment: Thank you very much @acw1668! Only a day back I had done the same after meticulous research, but using window.after(10,function_name) instead. Thanks a lot tho!